# What is the point of custom problem matchers if the problems they generate can never be removed or resolved?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was working with some very basic awk scripts that I had running with input piped from inotifywait to generate typescript classes with information from WebGL shaders whenever the shader source files changed. Works like a charm for what started as an extended oneliner.

Then I had the cute idea to start the whole thing from a vscode task with a custom problem matcher to see if I could get my 50 lines of script to also provide linting. I mean they were already looping through the files anyways.

Sure enough, no problems there. Just copy a problem matcher example from vscode's website, tweak it a bit to run in the background and then add some outputs from the awk script that matches the regex they used in the example. Works like a dream.

That is if it wasn't for the problems and error squiggles being impossible to remove after the have been generated...

I haven't really used the Tasks in vscode before so I am probably missing something. But what I'm getting from some googling is that there is no way for problem matchers or their tasks to remove any of the problems they generate, and this is the intended way because they are supposed to be handled by linting extensions and whatnot. They can't even be removed by the user manually.

Is this really the case? It seems like it would be incredibly useful to have project specific linters with just a short script and a regex.

I'll include my scripts along with the problem matcher below. I wouldn't caution against using my inotifywait+awk method for anything serious though. It's not particularly portable.

tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "prep-shaders",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "./tsc-shader.sh",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                },
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": false,
                    "beginsPattern": "^File change detected\\. Rebuilding '.+\\ts'$",
                    "endsPattern": "^Build complete\\.$"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tsc-shader.awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN { FS = "[ ;]"; }
function printErr(location, severity, message) {
    printf("%s: %s: %s\n", location, severity, message) > "/dev/stderr"
}
function addField(name, tstype, gltype, type) {
    loc = sprintf("%s:%d:%d", FILENAME, FNR, index($0, $1));
    errForm = "%s storage does not match declaration '%s' at '%s'";
    if (name in fields && fields[name]["gl"] != gltype) {
        printErr(loc, "error", sprintf(\
            errForm, name, fields[name]["type"], fields[name]["loc"]));
        if (fields[name]["err"]++ == 0)
            printErr(fields[name]["loc"], "error", sprintf(\
                errForm, name, type, loc));
    } else {
        fields[name]["ts"] = tstype;
        fields[name]["gl"] = gltype;
        fields[name]["loc"] = loc;
        fields[name]["type"] = type;
    }
}
($1 == "attribute") {
    addField($3, "number", "Attrib", "attribute")
}
($1 == "uniform") {
    addField($3, "WebGLUniformLocation | null", "Uniform", "uniform")
}
(FNR == 1) {
    n = split(FILENAME, arr, ".");
    printf("%sexport const %s_SOURCE: string = `\n",
        (FNR != NR ? "`\n" : ""), toupper(arr[n]));
}
{
    printf("\t%s\n", $0);
}
function declareProp(name, tstype) {
    printf("\tpublic readonly %s: %s;\n", name, tstype);
}
function setProp(name, gltype) {
    printf("%sthis.%s = gl.get%sLocation(\n%s\tthis.shaderProgram, '%s');\n",
        "\t\t", name, gltype, "\t\t", name);
}
END {
    printf("`;\nexport class ShaderInfo {\n");
    for (name in fields)
        declareProp(name, fields[name]["ts"]);
    printf("\tconstructor(\n\t\tpublic readonly shaderProgram: WebGLProgram,\n"\
        "\t\tgl: WebGL2RenderingContext) {\n");
    for (i in fields)
        declareProp(name, fields[name]["gl"]);
    printf("\t}\n}");
}
```

tsc-shader.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create -m src |
grep -P --line-buffered 'vert$|frag$' |
while read -r directory _ filename; do
    md5sum "$directory$filename"
done |
awk '
(!($2 in a) || a[$2] != $1) {
    a[$2] = $1;
    print(gensub(/^(.*\/)(.*)(\.vert$|\.frag$)/, "\\1\t\\2", "g", $2));
    fflush();
}
' |
while read -r dir name; do
    echo "File change detected. Rebuilding 'gen/$name.shader.ts'."
    ./tsc-shader.awk "$dir$name.vert" "$dir$name.frag" 2>&1 >"gen/$name.shader.ts"
    echo "Build complete."
done
```

File Structure:

```
./
| .vscode/                                                                                                                                                                                               
| | tasks.json
| gen/
| | gltest.shader.ts
| src/
| | gltest.frag
| | gltest.vert
| tsc-shader.awk*
| tsc-shader.sh*
```

- .vscode/

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup. I have a task, started by hand, that runs s a script that analyzes files in the project and prints the locations it finds with problems that match the script arguments. The problem matcher picks up the problems and shows them in the `Problems` tab.

When I fix a few problems and rerun the task/script these problems are removed from the `Problems` tab.

It seems the problems are kept/linked by the problem matcher. If I define a global problem matcher in `tasks.json` and a few tasks (with different script arguments) that use this problem matcher, the problems of the previous runned task are erased from the `Problems` tab if I run a Task that uses the global problem matcher.

I think the idea of the problem matcher is that it reports problems that you fix and then the task is run again to see if the problem is fixed.

If there is a problem in your shader you  fix it and the task is run again and the problem should be removed from the `Problems` tab.